# Fullcalendar not showing allDay event when start and end date are the same day and they contain the time

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I was wondering why fullcalendar (actually v. 3.5.1) doesn't show an event on the calendar if you set 'allDay:true' and the start and end attributes to the same day but with different time.

For example an event like this isn't shown:

```
{
  title: 'All Day with time',
  allDay: true,
  start: new Date(2017, 10, 1, 10, 0, 0),
  end: new Date(2017, 10, 1, 18, 0, 0)
}
```

I think fullcalendar should show the event even those I'm setting the event as an all day event but the difference beetwen the start and end time is less than 1 day.

Is it correct or it's a bug?

If I left out the time and I leave only the date with the same day it works correctly.

I've preparared a Reduced Test case on jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/yqs0jnhq/4/

Comment: This seems like a bug or implementation detail of the package. It would probably be best to check their documentation and reach out to their support.

Comment: I would think it doesn't know what to do with your event because it doesn't make any logical sense - an "all day" event, but with times attached. How should it know which of those things is correct, and the intention of the author? Probably safer to ignore it (and therefore potentially highlight the existence of a fault in the event data) than to display something incorrectly. Seems like a sensible way to deal with an ambiguous situation really. I guess it could put a warning on the console, that would be the only improvement I'd make, if it were me.

Comment: The event is, of course, weird but, on the contrary, if you create an event with allDay:true, the start attribute with the time set and not end attribute, this event will be shown correctly by fullcalender and even in this case it isn't really an "all day" event. It seems strange to me this different behaviour. So I would agree putting a warning on the console but probably in both cases (with end attribute and without end attribute).

Comment: In the case of the start time being set, I believe it simply ignores the time component, believing it to be a mistake. Since there's no end time, it's easy to believe it's intended to be an allday event (because if it weren't, an end time would be required). Although the docs do also say _"If either the start or end value has a "T" as part of the ISO8601 date string, allDay will become false. Otherwise, it will be true"_ (from https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/Event_Object/). So it can depend exactly how you specify the time, too. I don't think it applies your example using a Date object

Comment: But if you've got start and end with the same date but different times, it might start to think that the "allDay" is potentially a mistake, just like in the start-time-only example it thinks that the time was a mistake. But it can't be sure. Maybe both times were a mistake? It's much more ambiguous than the other scenario. For that reason I think the  situations are different and therefore I can understand why fullCalendar might behave differently.

Comment: But we're speculating. The best way to determine whether it's a bug or not is probably to raise a ticket on the project's GitHub page. Then it'll either get fixed, or closed as not being a bug, hopefully with a suitable explanation.

Comment: Thanks @ADyson, I did so https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/issues/3854

Comment: I've also done another experiment updating the https://jsfiddle.net/yqs0jnhq/4/ setting allDay: true and using the ISO8601 format for the start and end dates with the T part being set. The event is still ignored even those the documentation you cited above says the allDay will became false. https://jsfiddle.net/criluc/yqs0jnhq/11/